# Converting 3 column layout to one column always at top

Tags: css, layout, css-position, multiple-columns

I am using http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-32-fluid-fluid-fixed/  as the starting point. I want one of the column to always remain visible at the top. I put {position: fixed; top: 0} in the right column css, but that did not achieve what I wanted. It just made the right column content disappear.

How to achieve what I want (using css only, preferably no javascript, atleast no jquery).

Below is total code. Just 2 line modification from original one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Drive: CSS Liquid Layout #3.2- (Fluid-Fluid-Fixed)</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
}

b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#topsection{
background: #EAEAEA;
height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 200px 0 25%; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 right-column-width 0 left-column-width*/
}

#leftcolumn{
float: left;
width: 25%; /*Width of left column in percentage*/
margin-left: -100%;
background: #C8FC98;
}

#rightcolumn{
top: 0;  /* THIS IS ADDED LINE by me...... */
position: fixed; /* THIS IS ADDED LINE by me...... */
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of right column in pixels*/
margin-left: -200px; /*Set margin to -(RightColumnWidth)*/
background: #FDE95E;
}

#footer{
clear: left;
width: 100%;
background: black;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
color: #FFFF80;
}

.innertube{
margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
margin-top: 0;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*** Temporary text filler function. Remove when deploying template. ***/
var gibberish=["This is just some filler text", "Welcome to Dynamic Drive CSS Library", "Demo content nothing to read here"]
function filltext(words){
for (var i=0; i<words; i++)
document.write(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+" ")
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">

<div id="topsection"><div class="innertube"><h1>CSS Liquid Layout #3.2- (Fluid-Fluid-Fixed)</h1></div></div>

<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="contentcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Content Column: <em>Fluid</em></b> <script type="text/javascript">filltext(450)</script></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Left Column: <em>25%</em></b> <script type="text/javascript">filltext(20)</script></div>

</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Right Column: <em>200px</em></b> <script type="text/javascript">filltext(15)</script></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">Dynamic Drive CSS Library</a></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you think you could link us the relevant HTML and CSS that isn't working?

Comment: I copy pasted the code above. Lines added by me are with comments "THIS IS ADDED LINE BY ME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS puts the 3rd column off the left side of the screen that is why it is not visible.
Change your CSS from

```
#rightcolumn {
   top: 0;
   position: fixed;
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: -200px; 
   background: #FDE95E;
}
```

to

```
#rightcolumn {
   top: 0;
   position: fixed;
   width: 200px;
   right: 0;
   background: #FDE95E;
}
```